# count movements of values from 1 quarter to the other using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to count all 10's that moved to 20 from 1 Quarter to the other and total of all 10's in each Quarter
Below is the result i want

```
            2013            2014            2015           2016         
Quarters    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
movements   0   1   0   3   2   1   2   0   1   0   3   2   1   2   0   1
Total 10's  80  173 122 211 201 190 192 195 197 200 202 205 207 210 212 215
```

Sample input is like this

```
sn  acc          days   year    quarter
3   81011753418  10     2013    Q1
4   91011979519  10     2013    Q1
5   181018354017 10     2014    Q1
6   31012008913  10     2013    Q2
7   61015631812  10     2015    Q1
8   141010417018 10     2013    Q1
9   21010403313  10     2013    Q1
12  151013316811 20     2013    Q1
13  161017322412 10     2013    Q2
14  21010376715  30     2016    Q2
17  21010480814  10     2013    Q3
18  21010489714  20     2014    Q2
19  21010523211  10     2013    Q3
22  21010609717  20     2013    Q4
23  21010629214  10     2015    Q2
24  21010635915  30     2014    Q2
25  21010640412  10     2016    Q4
26  21010660618  10     2013    Q3
27  21010697813  10     2013    Q4
28  21010725019  10     2013    Q3
31  21010772629  10     2013    Q1
32  21010802412  20     2014    Q4
33  21010863713  10     2015    Q4
36  21011153817  20     2016    Q4
```

so far this is what i have tried

```
(pd.pivot_table(overdraft, values='PAST DUE DAYS', index='ACCOUNT ', columns=['Year', 'Quarter'], aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0).subtract(pd.pivot_table(overdraft, values='PAST DUE DAYS', index='ACCOUNT ', columns=['Year', 'Quarter'], aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0))).reset_index()
```

Comment: Can't you just index using something along the lines of `df['Q1'] == 10 & df['Q2'] == 20`? Please share a [mcve].

Comment: could you copy and paste a exampel of your dataframe? try `print(total_sum_of_tens.iloc[0:9,0:7])` and copy and paste it

Comment: @ansev the print(total_sum_of_tens.iloc[0:9,0:7]) gives me this error since its a list AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: @AMC Q1 is not a column so df['Q1'} not possiblle only becomes a column when pivoted

Comment: @EddieKwasiDankie Because you're using a MultiIndex, right? I know it's not exact, I wanted to share the general idea.

Comment: okay @AMC am a novice so pardon me

Comment: with `df.eq(10).sum()` you have second question, if you copy and paste an example i will solve first..

Comment: @ansev i dont get you

Comment: We need work with a example of your dataframe ir order to build a solution

Comment: okay @ansev how do i create that i have the sample data here                                             https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bmtPJ_V7JDq2Mbihtl4VEv45lavgd1UR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try: `(df.shift(axis = 1).eq(10)&df.eq(20)).sum().to_frame('Move to 20').join(df.eq(10).sum().rename('eq 10')).T` where `df` is  the pivoted DataFrame

Comment: @EddieKwasiDankie It's generally considered better to have all the necessary information in the post itself, since the contents of links, especially on sites like google drive, can and does change or disappear.

Comment: @AMC i dont know how to add the data

Comment: @ansev this is what i get how do i turn it to the final df                                         Unnamed: 0  S/N  ACCOUNT  ACCOUNT NAME  PAST DUE DAYS  ACCOUNT SEGMENT  Year  Quarter
Move to 20  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
eq 10  1  16  0  0  1293  0  0  0

Comment: you need join, see my answer